# Separate an int in two with xslt

Tags: xslt

Hello I am writing an xslt program and I have this problem. I would like to separate an int into two different int.
Let me show and example:

```
<node>
    <xsl:variable name="test" select="root/node/value"/>
    ...
    <xsl:variable name="first" .../>
    <xsl:variable name="second" .../>
    ...
    <xsl:value-of select="first"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="second"/>
</node>
```

Here value equals for example "1234" and first would be "12" and second "34".
I thinked of maybe divide the first one by 100 and keep the result as an int and for the second I still have no idea.
Is there an easier way to do it ?
Thank you.

Comment: What are the rules? It sounds more like a string operation than a numeric computation.

Comment: I think to, I have no specific rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing (!) you want to do:

```
floor($yourvalue div 100)
```

and:

```
$yourvalue mod 100
```

Comment: that is exactly what I wanted ! Thank you !